# Error while implementing a complex construct in C < char (*(*f())[]) () >

Tags: c

Error while implementing a complex construct in C.
Here is the piece of snippet I had tried.
'Where f is a function returning a pointer to an array of
pointers pointing to a function returning character.'

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

 char (*(*f())[]) ();

 char s () 
 {
      return 'y';
 }

char (*g[1])();
g[0] = s;
printf("%c\n",g[0]());


// here it's throwing error how to fix it?**strong text**    
(char (*(*)[])()) func()
{
    return g;
}

f = func;
printf("%c\n",(f())[0]());

return 0;
}
```

Error:

`enter code heremain.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:27:19: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘func’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 (char (*(*)[])()) func()
                   ^~~~
main.c:27:1: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
 (char (*(*)[])()) func()
 ^
main.c:28:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
main.c:33:1: error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
 printf("%c\n",(f())[0]());
 ^~~~~~
main.c:33:16: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
 printf("%c\n",(f())[0]());`

Comment: We can't help you if we don't know what the actual error is?

Comment: Why do you prototype inside `main()`?

Comment: Maybe you can save everyone time and just tell us the error. You are the one asking for help after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use typedefs to help:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char (*functionPtr)(void);
typedef char (**arrayOfFunctionPtr)(void);

// OR THIS
// typedef functionPtr* arrayOfFunctionPtr;

typedef arrayOfFunctionPtr (*functionReturningArrayOfFunctionPointers)(void);

int main()
{

    functionReturningArrayOfFunctionPointers f;

    char s() 
    {
        return 'y';
    }

    char (*g[1])();
    g[0] = s;
    printf("%c\n",g[0]());


    arrayOfFunctionPtr func()
    {
        return g;
    }

    f = func;
    printf("%c\n",(f())[0]());

    return 0;
}
```